# Simple usage of EF Core 3 results in error: Sequence contains more than one matching element

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I'm testing out usage of EF Core 3 for my application, and followed the "Getting started" section on the Microsoft Docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli)

I am using the corresponding PostgreSQL connector, to connect to my database.

I've created the following models:

- Blog

```
    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
        public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
```

- Post

```
   public class Post
   {
       public int PostId { get; set; }
       public string Title { get; set; }
       public string Content { get; set; }
       public Blog Blog { get; set; }
   }
```

Then, upon startup of the program I try to insert a new "Blog" into the database.

```
   using (var db = new BloggingContext())
   {
        db.Add(new Blog { Url = "http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet" });
        db.SaveChanges();
   }
```

This should be fine from my understanding. I then create the migrations, and run them against the database - and can see the the tables are created, with the correct Primary keys, and Foreign key.

Then, I receive this error upon starting the program:
`System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Query.ExpressionTranslators.Internal.NpgsqlStringMethodTranslator' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element`

I have tried for a long time to see what I'm doing wrong, but can't seem to figure it out.

Is there something completely wrong here?

Comment: It may be that the PostgreSQL provider isn't automatically treating your PKs as identity columns and assigning them a sequence. If you are expecting the DB to assign IDs automatically you may need to mark the PKs as Identity columns /w [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]. SQL Server's provider I believe defaults this by convention, other providers may not.

Comment: The exception message sounds like internal EF Core provider error. Thus most likely it is EF Core provider bug/issue, you'd better ask/report it to their issue tracker.

Comment: This is crashing? https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/blob/dev/src/EFCore.PG/Query/ExpressionTranslators/Internal/NpgsqlStringMethodTranslator.cs#L47 (One of those `.Single()` calls is returning more than one result)

Comment: Do you have a weird mis-match between the framework version and library version? Though I don't think `typeof(string)` has ever had more than those 2 `Substring` methods...

Answer (score 0):

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Query.ExpressionTranslators.Internal.NpgsqlStringMethodTranslator' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element

From the Exception message, the type `NpgsqlStringMethodTranslator` called either `.Single()` or `.SingleOrDefault()`, while initialising a static member. But the sequence had 2 or more items.

The source code of this type is available [online](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/blob/dev/src/EFCore.PG/Query/ExpressionTranslators/Internal/NpgsqlStringMethodTranslator.cs#L47). I'm seeing calls to `.Single()` to locate 2 system methods and 2 extension methods. However they look fine to me. There should be exactly one matching result in each case.

You mentioned EF Core 3, all I can suggest is that you verify that the versions of the framework and nuget packages are consistent. Perhaps add the relevant sections of your .csproj file to your question if you can't see any obvious problems.